# Is there any Number recognition SDK or frameworks or libraries for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I need number recognition for my project, as i will write the number using touches. i want that to be recognized.

Can anyone Please Help me, provide me any ideas or frameworks or libraries related to this.

Answer (score 1):

this might get you started http://code.google.com/p/dollar-touch/